# Python or C++: Hijack http request to modify destination

Tags: c++, python, http, caching

This may be hard to explain, so I will use an example to illustrate the point.

I would like to be able to hijack http requests and (possibly) modify them on their way out programaticaly using C++ or Python (preferably Python since I know it better). Ultimately, I would like to achieve something similar to what web browsers do when serving cached objects.

**Example**

When you download a file `http://www.example.com/image.jpg` (from any website) it gets saved somewhere on the filesystem such that the next requests that the user's computer makes to that file (whether via a browser or `wget` in linux etc.) will be pointed to the copy on the filesystem.

In short, I would like to be able to detect an outgoing request to `http://www.example.com/image.jpg` and modify to something like `/tmp/files/image.jpg`.

This will form part of a bigger research project that we are working on.

I am having a hard time explaining this, so please let me know if I need to provide more details.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You have to make a *proxy*. A program that the clients connect to, and in turns connects to the real server. That's the only way to do it.

Comment: So you want to run code on client PC and on fly tweak requests which coming from Browser?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg This sounds exactly like it what I need, can you point to any resources if you know any. I will try googling too. Mailerdaimon, I don't have any code yet. I was looking for a starting point (an approach, not exactly code). The reason why I indicated my interest in doing it in Python or C++ was to determine if they would be sufficient to deliver the required functionality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most reasonable way to do this would be implementing a [proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server). You can then configure the browser to use the proxy and every request for resources from the internet will be routed to the proxy instead.

Writing a proxy server in Python shouldn't be too difficult as all the low-level details are already handled by the standard library (e.g. [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html)). You can also look at projects like [proxpy](https://code.google.com/p/proxpy/) that seem would be a good starting point.

Another more annoying but more general way would be working at a network level by routing all traffic through a specific machine where you can decide what to do. Note that however some protocols are designed so that only the intended receiver can understand the request and only the sender will be able to interpret the result: for that kind of traffic you can only observe pure noise being sent forth and back and nothing can be done without breaking the communication.

Comment: Thank you for your input @6502. Do you by any chance have any resources you can refer me to before I close the thread? Thanks again.

Comment: @Sthe: Added some links, see edit